# Implement jquery fullscreen image slider yii 2 project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii2

I'm trying to implement a slider in my yii2 project, I started using yii last week I don know if I'm doing the right thing here, I downloaded [this](http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/jquery-resizable-fullscreen-gallery-plugin/full_screen_preview/1591675) code, but the way I'm using it is not working 100%, the images and the thumbnails are showing, but I can't click on the thumbnails to change the background, the original code is working fine, the problem is I can't make it work in my yii project

```
<?php
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Cake::find(),

]);
?>

<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_bolos',
    'summary' => '',
    'options' => [
        'tag' => 'div',
        'id' => 'gallery',
        'class' => 'bigImages',
    ],

]); ?>
```

_bolos:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $model \app\models\Cake */

?>

<script>
    <?php $this->beginBlock('page-script') ?>
    (function () {

        $("#gallery").fullscreenGallery();

    })();
    <?php $this->endBlock() ?>
</script>

<?php $this->registerJs($this->blocks['page-script']) ?>


<div id="gallery">
    <div class="bigImages">
        <ul>
            <li> <?= Html::img($model->cakePhotos[0]->getUploadUrl('file'), ['width' => '100%']); ?></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <ul>
            <li> <?= Html::img($model->cakePhotos[0]->getThumbUploadUrl('file')); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Widget `ListView` will render `_bolos.php` view for each `Cake` model that will be retrieved from `$dataProvider`. 
Therefore you page will contain few `#gallery` div elements and js scripts (see your page source code). Therefore it can't be correctly initialized.

You need to move all elements that should not repeat to main view.